# How to change flutter app keyboard color?

Tags: flutter, colors, keyboard

In my flutter , I create a TextFormField, but it's keyboard color is black in iOS, I want to know how to change it to white.

flutter language version: >=2.2.2 <3.0.0

this is my code about the TextFormField:

```
TextFormField(
     style: TextStyle(
               fontSize: 14,
               color: Colors.black),
               autofocus: false,
               initialValue: 'initial value', 
               maxLines: 1,
               // onSaved: (String value) => _person = value,
               // obscureText: _isObscure,
               validator: (String value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'nononono';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
               decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'please make sure',
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 5, 15, 5),
               hintStyle: TextStyle(
                             color: Colors.grey,
                             fontSize: 12,
                             ),
               hasFloatingPlaceholder: false,
               // contentPadding: contentPadding,
               border: InputBorder.none,
               ),
),
```

when I click this TextFormField

what I get:
black keyboard

what I want:
white keyboard

Answer (score 12, accepted):

White keyboard use `Brightness.light`

Black keyboard use `Brightness.dark`

```
    body: Center(
            child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    keyboardAppearance: Brightness.light, // no matter what you set, it simply shows white keyboard
                )
            ],
            ),
        )
```

Comment: Just FYI, per the docs, "This setting is only honored on iOS devices." : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/keyboardAppearance.html

Comment: In fact doesn't seem to work on Android. Any Solution?

Comment: @Apoleo This trick is only working on ios. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/keyboardAppearance.html

Comment: @AmitPrajapati I got that, are there any solution for Android?

Comment: @Apoleo I'm sorry I didn't found anything for android.

Answer (score 6):

If you use `ThemeData` for global styling of your app, you can set `primaryColorBrightness`. The keyboard of a text field will use this brightness (light or dark) if no value is given for `keyboardAppearance`.

```dart
final ThemeData themeDark = ThemeData(
  primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
  // ...
);
```

This has the advantage that you don't have to define `keyboardAppearance` for each text field.

See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/keyboardAppearance.html

Comment: I used: `brightness: Brightness.dark,` in `ThemeData`